# how to add JTable in JFrame at Run time?

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jtable

I am using a JFrame & JPanel to create a frame.JFrame contains comboboxes,CheckBoxes,JLabels etc.Layout of JPanel is set to "null",because i am using setBounds(int,int,int,int) to set the position of components on JFrame.

There is also a JButton(named as "Submit").On submit button i have added actionListener,so that if i click on this button,A table will generate on frame(at runtime).

JTable is successfully displaying on JFrame but Table columns name are not displaying along with JFrame(Only table data is displaying when submit button is pressed).

I am also using setBounds with JTable.What should i have to do in this case ?

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       Object ColumnName[] = {"Document Name", "Modified Date", "Size(in MB)"};
       Object data[][] = { {"test.txt", "24-Oct-2011", "540"}};
       table = new JTable(data,ColumnName);
       table.setBounds(20,230,330,100);
       panel.add(table);
       panel.repaint();
       panel.revalidate();
     }
});
```

Give me your all valuable suggestions soon.
Thank you.

Comment: `Give me your all valuable suggestions soon. Thank you.` == then follows suggestion by @Amn +1, there are all valuable stuff

Comment: @mKorbel Sir i followed the same way which was suggested by Amn.But this is not working,all components are not add to the frame after using this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may it works  `revalidate();`  method of panel . `call` after setting table on panel.
but `JScrollPane` is best way to do this.

Comment: I have used repaint() & revalidate() methods after adding table to panel.All RowData(Data) is displaying but without column Name.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you couldn't:

1. Use `setBounds(int, int, int, int)`, because this is job for [`LayoutManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
2. Recreate [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) at run time.  Just implement [`DefalutTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), there you can add/remove `TableRows`, reset `TableModel` - all changes are immediately displayed in `JTable`.

And you could:

1. (As mentioned both posters) put `JTable` into a [`JScrollPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).
2. Go through examples from the table tutorial and tons of Swing related examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm).

Comment: sir i am not using any LayoutManager(set to null).So thats why i am using setBounds() method.

Comment: My Headername problem is solved. I am using two JPanels panel1 & panel2. panel1 contains all the components(including Submit Button) and panel2 contains the jtable(when submit button is clicked).But now the jtable is displaying on whole frame(including panel1).Can you suggest me solution to fix the both panels positions.

Comment: depends what JComponents are pleaced into 1st. JPanel, if is there only services for JTable, then follows tutorial for BorderLayout and place this JPanel to the NORTH or SOUTH area and JTable (inside JScrollPanel)to the CENTER area, then you GUI is pretty resiziable, better would be start new thread about layout JCompoentns in the GUI, only a few JComponents, there are going about idea how to do it, not how to debug your your project :-) idea is described http://sscce.org/, then a chance of getting correct answer is higher

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add JTable into a JScrollPane first and then add that JScrollPane into your main panel.

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtable);
```

Have a look at this: [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

EDIT: this thread discusses the same issue: [Jtable Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944819/defaulttablemodel-without-column-names/7944858#comment9709419_7944858)

Comment: I am using only a JPanel,according to you i have added JScrollPane into my main Panel,but its not working.Edit :  That thread was relates with database.

Comment: I would assume that you would have to add the JPanel into your JFrame. SO the way its linked is: scrollpane.add(table) --> panel.add(scrollpane) --> frame.add(panel)

Comment: table = new JTable(data,ColumnName);
     table.setBounds(20,230,330,100);
     panel.add(table);
     panel.repaint();
     panel.revalidate();       I am adding Jtable to Jframe by this way.Thia code is written at actionListener(at submit button)

Comment: instead of adding the table into your panel, add it to a JScrollPane as I showed in my original reply and then add this scroll pane to your JPanel and finally add the JPanel to JFrame. Everything else would be same. JScrollPane creates a viewport for your table with column headers and scroll bars.

Comment: I did according to your suggestion,but its not working.Now even data is also not displaying.I want to ask that whether i have to declare JScrollPane scrollpane=new JScrollPane(); inside actionListener or outside.

Comment: you can declare JScrollPane outside of action listener, may be in the class constructor and inside your actionlistener, you can instantiate it passing the jtable in the constructor like my original reply.

Comment: table = new JTable(data,ColumnName);
    table.setBounds(20,230,330,100);
    scroll.add(table);
    panel.add(scroll) ;
    panel.repaint();
    panel.revalidate();
    frame.add(panel);  Using this code other components are also not displaying.